# PostGreSql Get Unique combination of two columns using Having Max Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am using postGreSql. I have a currency conversion table which has following columns DateOfClosing, fromCurrency, toCurrency, closingRate. dateOfClosing is in varchar format
I want to find latest unique combination of fromCurrency and toCurrency from past 5 days
for example if table contents following

```
DateOfClosing    fromCurrency     toCurrency   closingRate
2020-06-25       INR              USD          1
2020-06-26       INR              USD          3
2020-06-26       JPY              USD          2
2020-06-24       THB              USD          1
```

It should return:

```
DateOfClosing    fromCurrency     toCurrency   cloisingRate
2020-06-26        INR             USD          3
2020-06-26        JPY             USD          2
2020-06-24        THB             USD          1
```

I tried using groupby with having max clause but getting error because of varchar to date conversion. Can someone give me a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fromCurrency, toCurrency) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY fromCurrency, toCurrency, DateOfClosing DESC;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (fromCurrency, toCurrenty) t.*
from mytable t
where dateOfClosing >= current_date - interval '5 day'
order by fromCurrency, toCurrenty, dateOfClosing desc
```